# How do I convert a list of strings to a new list where each element is its core type?

Tags: python, list, types, type-conversion

For example,

I have a list

```
list = ['1', 'hello', '524', '65.23']
```

how to I convert it to:

```
list_new = [1, 'hello', 524, 65.23]
```

where every element is no longer a string but it's actual type.

where instead of being [string, string, string, string] it's now [int, string, int, float]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import ast
>>> items = ['1', 'hello', '524', '65.23']
>>> def convert(x):
        try:
            return ast.literal_eval(x)
        except:
            return x


>>> [convert(x) for x in items]
[1, 'hello', 524, 65.23]
```

Comment: Jamylak!!!! Where have you been!!!!! (also you beat me +1)

Comment: To handle strings with spaces or strings that start with numeric characters you should catch `SyntaxError` as well.

Comment: Ok changed to plain `except` to handle everything